# Measure with indexable name

Tags: mdx, saiku

I'm trying to do a search using ordering and paging, but without success, I mean, it's works, but not like I was expecting
I'm doing a search like this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[indexable_name] AS 
    [myDimension].[name].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
SELECT 
  SubSet
  (
    Order
    (
      {
        [myDimension].[id].MEMBERS
       ,[myDimension].[name].MEMBERS
      }
     ,[Measures].[indexable_name]
     ,ASC
    )
   ,0
   ,20
  ) ON ROWS
 ,{[Measures].[indexable_name]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [myCube];
```

that bring to me something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOQJC.png)
"nome" is the name of my item and indexable_name are the unique name

So, my problem is, when I'm doing the paging in my java code, I only can take half of what I want to, because I'm looking for two rows to take all the information that I need(id and name), there's some way to put all the information in one row to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You may join name of two attributes in one by an extra measure:

```
With 
Member [Measures].[indexable_name] as 
[myDimension].[name].CurrentMember.uniqueName

Member [Measures].[DimsName] as 
[myDimension].[id].CurrentMember.Name + ' ' + [myDimension].[name].CurrentMember.Name

select 
Subset(
    Order(
        {[myDimension].[id].Members,[myDimension].[name].Members},
        [Measures].[indexable_name],ASC
    ),
    0,
    20
) on rows,
{[Measures].[DimsName],[Measures].[indexable_name]} on columns
from [myCube]
```

Comment: I was a problem to create that measure [Measures].[DimsName] is like I can't concatenate these two strings.
But I solve the problem with some changes, I'm taking now only the id and in my java code I can take the name taking the caption of parent member.
I'm glad for you help